# Newline Break when saving innerHTML to text file I automatically get a newline Break in the saved Text file or when reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, activex

The result in the text file is always saving the file with a linebreak  not just the p tag in div1 when clicking the button.
example:

```
<p>x1</p>
....linebreak
```

If I  click the button 3 time and reload the page and click the button again I get this as well.

```
<p>x1</p><p>x2</p><p>x3</p>

<p>x1</p>
```

html code:

```
    <button id="btn" value="" onclick="btn();return false"style="margin:1px"> Write to file </button>
    <div id="div1" style="width:200px; border:1px; margin:5px 0px;"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
// Read or Write to file
    var path = 'c:\\home\\lab.txt';
    var num = 0 ;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('div1');

    // Read or Write to file
    var path = 'c:\\home\\lab.txt';
    var num = 0 ;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('div1');
    myDiv.innerHTML = readFileInIE(path);

    function readFileInIE(path) {//Read file content
            try {
                   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                   var file = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1);
                   var rfileContent = file.ReadAll();
                   file.Close();
                   return rfileContent;
            } catch (err) {
                    alert('Unable to access local files or location. '+ err);
                    return  "";
            //}  
        }

    
    function btn(){ //onClick Calls writeFileInIE and paragraph to file on new line.
        num++;
        var myInput= "P" + num.toString();
        var myPara =  '<p>'  +  myInput + '</p>';
        
        myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + MyPara;
        writeFileInIE(path, myDiv.innerHTML);
    }

    function writeFileInIE(filePath, fileContent) { //Write to file function
        
        try {
                var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var file = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2, true);
                file.WriteLine(fileContent);
                file.Close();
                return fileContent;

        } catch (err) {
            alert('Unable to access local files or location.'); 
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

My goal is to be able to write to the file only the innerHTML from the div1 element innerHTML to the text only content in this format.
example in exact format I want even on a reload to the text file :

```
<p>x1</p>
<p>x2</p>
<p>x3</p>
<p>x1</p>
<p>x2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test your code but i see you comment and ending } , probably that is messing with your code.

//} after the return you should uncomment

```
function readFileInIE(path) {//Read file content
            try {
                   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                   var file = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1);
                   var rfileContent = file.ReadAll();
                   file.Close();
                   return rfileContent;
            } catch (err) {
                    alert('Unable to access local files or location. '+ err);
                    return  "";
            //}  
        }
```

After that, try put a `<br>` maybe it will do that break you want

```
var myPara =  '<p>'  +  myInput + '</p><br/>';
```

Comment: See my last post  as it's not what I was trying to explain was the issue. see below.

Comment: When I refresh the data disappear so I cant reproduce, but try to delete the \n that you have         var myPara =  '<p>'  +  myInput + '</p>'+'\n'; 
p is already a paragraph it will change the line without that. Also missing a ; in this part var myCode ="";

Answer (score 0):

Ok many be with this you will see what I mean by not getting the correct format and it keeps adding a line break to the file c:\lab.txt. It works fine the with the button.
Until I reload the page or refresh it I get a newline Break so I end up with this

```
<p>P1</p>
<p>P2</p>

<p>P1</p>

<p>P1</p>
<p>P2</p>
<p>P3</p>
```

I want it to do this:

```
<p>P1</p>
<p>P2</p>
<p>P1</p>
<p>P3</p>
<p>P1</p>
<p>P2</p>
<p>P3</p>
```

I want it to allways save the file with out blank line breaks between the P tags.
It fine if I star with a blank document but once it reloads with data in the text file.
I will get a new linebreak saves in the middle.

Try to use the new code I have posted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Page OPEN</title>
<Script language="JavaScript">//*/alert("helloWorld".toUpperCase())
</Script>
</head>

<body>
    <h5> "Lab.txt file populating div1.innerHTML that is being changed via JavaScript while being save to Lab.txt"</h5>
    <div id="div1" style="width:600px; height:150px; border:1px dotted; margin:5px 0px; overflow: scroll;"></div>
  
    <table>
                </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button id="btn1" value="" onclick="btnWrite();return false"> Write to file </button></td>
            <td><button id="btn2" value="" onclick="btnRead() ;return false"> Read from file</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content Sent to file</td>
            <td>File Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><pre id="pre1" style='border:1px solid red ; width:300px; height: 300px; overflow: scroll;'></pre>1</td>
            <td><pre id="pre2" style='border:1px solid blue; width:300px; height: 300px; overflow: scroll;'></pre>2</td>

    </table>
    <div id="lastDiv"></div>


<Script language="JavaScript">//*/alert("helloWorld".toUpperCase())
    var lDiv = document.getElementById('lastDiv')
    // Read or Write to file
    var path = 'c:\\home\\lab.txt'; // Change to any location will create the file.
    var num = 0 ;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('div1');
    myDiv.innerHTML = readFileInIE(path);
    
    function btnRead(){ //onClick Calls writeFileInIE and paragraph to file on new line.
        
        document.getElementById('pre2').innerText = readFileInIE(path);
        //document.getElementById("pre2").innerText = "hello";
    }

    function readFileInIE(readPath) {//Read file content
            try {
                   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                   var file = fso.OpenTextFile(readPath, 1);
                   var readFileContent = file.ReadAll();
                   file.Close();
                   return readFileContent;
            } catch (err) {
                    tkr("Error on reading: "+ path + " - " + err);//alert('Unable to access local files or location. '+ err);
                    return  "";
            }  
        }

    

    function btnWrite(){ //onClick Calls writeFileInIE and paragraph to file on new line.
        num++;
        var myCode =""
        var myInput= "P" + num.toString();
        var myPara =  '<p>'  +  myInput + '</p>'+'\n';
        
        myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + myPara;

        document.getElementById('pre1').innerText = writeFileInIE(path, myDiv.innerHTML);
        document.getElementById('pre2').innerText = readFileInIE(path);
    }

    function writeFileInIE(filePath, wFileContent) { //Write to file function
        
        try {
                var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var file = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2, true);
                file.WriteLine(wFileContent);
                file.Close();
                return wFileContent;

        } catch (err) {
            tkr("Error on write file: "+ path + " - "+ err);//alert('Unable to access local files or location.'); 
            file.Close();
            return err;
        }
    }
   
    //*/

        // track locations and find errors debug 
    function tkr(myData){lDiv.innerHTML = lDiv.innerHTML + "<p>" + myData + "</p>";}
    tkr("JavaScript complete onload");
</Script>


</body>
</html>
```